# Assigning values to a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, assign

I have a dictionary which has a key for names and empty lists for values.
i have a random number generator for a hypothetical score.
eg.(name: , [,,,,,,])   ( the test is scored from 0 to 100)
 im trying to assign 6 different tests to a different number of people . i would then use an algorithm i have made to make a total score for their scores and put them in a top to bottom position. id probably use something along these algorithms that i have made but currently im trying to understand how to assign the values to the list. This is the code to figure out the total series score according to the number tests that are valid.

```
def series_score(y,choice):
while choice >1:
    y[1].remove(max(y[1]))
    choice =choice - 1
x = sum(y[1]) - max(y[1])
return x
```

this is the sort of sort i would use

```
results = [('Alice',[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
('Bob', [3, 1, 5, 3, 2, 5]),
('Clare',[2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2]),
('Dennis', [5, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4]),
('Eva', [4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3])]

def sort_series(results):
    return sorted(results, key=lambda order: (sum(order[1]), order[0]))

print(sort_series(results))
```

and then the random number gen from previous data using a bell curve of where the people may get in the test:

```
import csv
import random
import operator

def sort_dis_data():
f = open('data.csv','r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
new_dict = {}

for row in reader:
    new_dict[row[0]] = random.gauss(float(row[1]), float(row[2]))

order_list = sorted(new_dict, key =lambda k: new_dict[k], reverse = False)
return order_list
```

any help would be grand.

Comment: So what you're trying to accomplish is to add up all the numbers in the list for each person, then return the ordering of the people from highest score to lowest? So [Eva, Dennis, Clare, Alice]? Those users have 25, 24, 15, and 7 sums respectively.

Comment: yes but that was sample data. i have to create  a new set of data using the sort dis data which stands for sort distributed data

Comment: I think `dict.items()` might work, as it returns a tuple and you can use `for` loop to assigning new values to the dictionary.

Comment: @Struggler can you provide 3-4 lines from your data.csv file in your question?

Comment: the data file looks like this                                                                                  
 line 1 :name,mean,stardard dev                                                                                     
line 2 : jon,     X,        X 
etc

Comment: I was too lazy to calculate any kind of standard dev so I just put 10101. But your line looks like this? The last 6 numbers are the tests scores from your example: Eva,4.16,10101,4,5,3,5,5,3

Comment: its because in the test i made the test out of 5 instead of 100 , anyway how would i use dict. items to add values @PreetkaranSingh

Comment: adding values to a dictionary to any key can be done by using `for` loop`; For example, dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4]}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    value.append(5)`; result would be `{'a':[1,2,3,4,5]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Struggler, if you want to get the total of the scores of each individual name entered in the dictionary, and then sort them from highest to lowest total score, then I think, the best way would be:

Here's a sample code:

```
dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [1,2,3,4,5], 'c': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    total = sum(value)
    dictionary[key] = total

dictionary = sorted(dictionary.items(), key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

This sample code would sum up all the score values entered for every individual key and then sort them by values in reverse order, returning a list of tuples containing key and the total score value.

Hope this answers your question.